# Get id of record with lowest value Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a product that has many options. Options is for example price, size and availability. I want to get the value of availability for the option with the lowest price, how can I do that? Or just the id for the option with the lowest price. Right now I´m just getting the value of the lowest price.

```
product = Product.find(params[:id])
minimum_price = product.options.minimum(:price)
```

Comment: `product.options.order(:price).first` should return the first option with the smallest price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the lowest priced option's availability:

```
product.options.order(:price).first.availability
```

Or you can get the id instead using this code:

```
product.options.order(:price).first.id
```

Comment: Isn't it better to call `.limit(1)[0]` instead of `.first`? This allows active-record to not have to order/load the whole database.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to order the options on the price field and retrieve the first one. Something like this

```
options = product.options.order(:price).first
```